# Logback TCP appender with JDK 17 and Spring boot 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, java-17

After upgrading to JDK 17 and Spring boot 3.0.5, I am getting following error at start up

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender[tcp-logstash] - Unable to create ssl context java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such secure random algorithm: SHA1PRNG
```

**Logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">

    
    <appender name="tcp-logstash" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>na-esaas.intranet:8888</destination>
        <ringBufferSize>1024</ringBufferSize>
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder" >
            <customFields>{
                "app":"",
                "es_id":"",
                "es_ver":"0.02",
                "api": "",
                "env_name":"",
                "app_id":"",
                "category":"app"
                }
            </customFields>
        </encoder>

        <ssl>
            <trustStore>
                <location>file:/etc/esaas/keystore/esaas-keystore.jks</location>
                <password>****</password>
            </trustStore>
            <keyStore>
                <location>file:/etc/esaas/keystore/esaas-keystore.jks</location>
                <password>****</password>
            </keyStore>
        </ssl>
    </appender>
    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <!-- To enable JMX Management -->
    <jmxConfigurator />

    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%d %green(%t)] %highlight(%-5p) %logger{36} - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.sides" level="INFO" />

    <root level="ERROR">
        <!--<appender-ref ref="tcp-logstash" />-->
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**POM**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I think you'll probably find the answer [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/usingSSL.html), *possibly* more specifically the [random config](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/usingSSL.html#SecureRandomFactoryBean)

Comment: I tried adding the <secureRandom>
    <algorithm>Xoshiro256PlusPlus</algorithm>
    <provider>SunJSSE</provider>
   </secureRandom>

But no luck . same error

Comment: As a matter of interest, do you have a Sun/Oracle jre?

Comment: I am using Openjdk 17

Comment: I don't know for certain that my analysis is correct, but afaics, that SHA1PRNG algo is *proprietary*, which means it's probably not going to be present in *your* JDK. You *probably* need to find the one that is